# Calculate right inset for microstrip antenna to match trasmission line

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna, microstrip

So,
I have designed a **2.4Ghz microstrip antenna**. I have chosen a **dielectric height of 1.5 mm** with a **dielectric constant of 4.08**

I calculated my W and L of the antenna and simulated it in CST. I have tweaked to better fit the S-parameter to 2.4Ghz and I came out with
**W=41mm and L=30.2mm**

Now, I would like to match my antenna to **50Ω** but I haven't found formulas to calculate the inset dimension (width and length).

After various simulations, I came up with a W=1.5mm (same of the dielectric) and a length L=7.16mm but they didn't come with mathematics calculation instead with "random" simulations. (transmission line is **0.035mm thicker and 2.98 wide** (why?! I don't know))

You can check a sketch of my antenna with a measure below.

[image]

Comment: Reinventing is fun but why not search?

Comment: I've searched and, honestly, I've found some good paper but, I still can't understand which are the parameters to start with. Like the width of the transmission line, is it random? Is it calculated to match something? Same question for the high; why 0.035mm? I can't find an explanation given the rectangular antenna shape, how to calculate the right dimensions for the feeding line and the inset

Comment: Track width/height above ground plane ratio is inverse to impedance affected by Dk.  Saturn PCB.exe can help with that

Comment: Ok I got the impedance of my line calculated. Now I need formulas to match with my antenna...